# Can we find all backlinks to a webpage?

Tags: web-crawlers, backlinks

In Page and Brin's paper on PageRank, they say that while you are guaranteed to be able to find all links that point away from a page, the reverse is not true. My impression from reading the paper was that finding all backlinks to a particular page is not an easy task.

**My main question is whether it is possible to find all backlinks to a particular web page.**

You may include in your answer any context that is relevant, for example, by answering the sub-questions below:

- How have things changed since they wrote the paper?
- If things have not changed, how on earth do SEO tools purport to give you all the
  backlinks when using their tool?

Comment: Guys, I've edited the question to make it more specific. Please re-open it, or let me know what else I need to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Much has changed. For one thing, PageRank is no longer the end all be all that it used to be. The PageRank tool is no longer actively supported, for example. (PageRank is still a part of the algorithm but it's a small part - one of the hundreds of factors.)

Google Search Console has become very good at finding the domains that link to you, but it mostly lists the top metrics; it might omit some of the lower-level info.

The best tool for backlinks that I've come across is Moz's Open Site Explorer:

https://moz.com/researchtools/ose/

The free version is great, but with a subscription, you get unlimited crawls and in-depth info. (I don't work for Moz; as an SEO, I've just found this to be the best tool for the job, by far.) Rogerbot, Moz's crawler, is great at indexing the web. Since the web is an interconnected network of links, and following links is what web crawlers do, finding backlink metrics is now one of the more basic tasks of these crawlers.